# Google Closure Editor Plugin (Eclipse or IntelliJ)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, google-closure

I can't get [Eclipse plugin for JavaScript with Closure Compiler, Closure Library and Closure Linter](http://www.normalesup.org/~simonet/soft/ow/eclipse-closure-javascript.en.html) to work properly. Everytime I try to build my app the compiler throws an error without any useful hints.

Maybe my app structure is not correct?

- When I exlcude the goog-lib from the source folder and just set the plugins base path it compiles but wont find any goog libraries.
- When I include the google-lib into the source folder it sometimes throws an NullPointer-Exeption or ends up in an heap-space error. Max size is already 2048m.

[image]

Using Eclipse Luna on Win7(64bit).

Any ideas? Or does someone know a similar plugin for IntelliJ?

Comment: What error? Even if you don't think it's helpful, perhaps someone else will?

Comment: I've added pictures of both error. I don't know if I can get more detailed logging from eclipse on this?

Comment: You can certainly get more log in http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: More log:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.google.javascript.jscomp.Compiler.getSourceFileByName(Compiler.java:2243)
 at com.google.javascript.jscomp.RhinoErrorReporter$NewRhinoErrorReporter.warning(RhinoErrorReporter.java:240)
 at com.google.javascript.rhino.head.Parser.addWarning(Parser.java:152)
 at com.google.javascript.rhino.head.Parser.addWarning(Parser.java:142)
 at com.google.javascript.rhino.head.Parser.warnTrailingComma(Parser.java:3462)
 at com.google.javascript.rhino.head.Parser.objectLiteral(Parser.java:3157)
 at ...